# React Scripts 86 Vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs

I just create an `react app` with create-react-app but I see that my project had 86 vulnerabilities, so I thought it was strange so I try to reinstall the dependencies, and when I was installing react-scripts I receive an message that are 86 vulnerabilities on my project: This is normal ?

```
found 86 vulnerabilities (82 moderate, 4 high)
```

Comment: A package.json would help, could you please show at least the versions of the dependencies. I recently started a project and I'm getting similar warnings but things are going smoothly and there is no groundbreaking errors. I guess it's just some version conflict between peer dependencies.

Comment: @Akash those are reported vulnerabilities, not conflicts. OP note that CRA pulls in ~1,900 packages, yes it's normal that sometimes there will be vulnerabilities reported in there somewhere (currently: `postcss`, `glob-parent`, `normalize-url`, `browserslist`, `css-what`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `npm audit fix` to fix some of these warning automatically. If you wish, you could got through the warnings and fix them manually by `npm audit`.
Last but not the least, you could `npm audit --force`. I would not recommend this since this can break your project.

If I were you, I'd not worry about them too much.

Comment: `npm audit fix` almost certainly won't work in a project you just created, because the latest versions matching the requirements are already installed. Generally you need to wait for upstream maintainers (CRA, the vulnerable packages or somewhere in between) to update their packages and published fixed versions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe for now do you think I have only to wait? Can I post the project on the web or I will have problems?

Comment: @Gabriellcreiss there isn't a straightforward answer to that. It will depend on which features of CRA you're using (those dependencies might not be involved at all), whether those dependencies are run- or build-time (they might only be used on development/CI machines, not running in your users' browsers), what your appetite for risk (based on likelihood and severity of consequences) is, etc.